# function to query DB with multiple filters

Tags: php

I'm trying to write a single function that queries a database, with results dependent on what is passed.
So far I have the following, but I can't help thinking there's a more succinct way to achieve this.

Additionally if I use a value of `0` all results get returned - like the `0` is a value of `false`, even if I pass it as a string.

I notice within WordPress strings are passed into functions (e.g. `cat=1&posts_per_page=5`). I couldn't quite figure out how this worked, but it looks like a nicer way of doing things.

Any help appreciated.

```
public static function sub_packages($subname_id = false, $region_id = false, $recurrence = false) {
    global $wpdb, tbl_packages;  

    if ( $subname_id ) $subname_id = " `package_subname` = $subname_id";
    if ( $region_id ) $region_id = " `package_region` = $region_id";
    if ( $recurrence ) $recurrence = " `package_recurrence` = $recurrence";

    // one
    if ( $subname_id && !$region_id && !$recurrence )
        $filter = " WHERE $subname_id";
    elseif ( !$subname_id && $region_id && !$recurrence )
        $filter = " WHERE $region_id";
    elseif ( !$subname_id && !$region_id && $recurrence )
        $filter = " WHERE $recurrence";
    // two
    elseif ( $subname_id && $region_id && !$recurrence )
        $filter =  " WHERE $subname_id AND $region_id";
    elseif ( $subname_id && !$region_id && $recurrence )
        $filter =  " WHERE $subname_id AND $recurrence";
    elseif ( !$subname_id && $region_id && $recurrence )
        $filter =  " WHERE $region_id AND $recurrence";
    // three
    elseif ( $subname_id && $region_id && $recurrence )
        $filter =  " WHERE $subname_id AND $region_id AND $recurrence";

    return $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM ". tbl_packages . $filter, ARRAY_A);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out how [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/development/server-side/php_mysql) does this:

```
$sWhere = "WHERE (";
for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ ) 
{
    $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i]." LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['sSearch'] )."%' OR ";
}
$sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -3 );
$sWhere .= ')';
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course there is.

- What do you want sql query to return? (single record, multi-record (array like), all data)
- Which cells you want to select?
- What is the table name you want to do your query on?
- Where are the DB Table cell names & values to do query?
- How do you order returned results?
- How do you limit (paginate) results?

These are the first questions you have to ask yourself when you try to create universal query functions / methods.

Here is a simple example;

```
function getData ($tableName= "members", $type = "array", $select = "*", $data = NULL, $order = array("id"=>"DESC"), $pagination = array("100"=>NULL)) { }
```

Now code above has some features;

### $tableName

Obvious (:

### $type

**Array** = Helps you to do query with an array and returns results as an array. **$data** must be an array.

**id** = Helps you to do a query with specific ID. **$data** must be integer.

**all** = Returns all data. You just need to use **$type** = all and **$select** = "*" (or any cell you want to select)

**single** = When you don't know ID but you need single result. **$data** must be an array.

### $select

If you have big database and if you use all the time * to select all cells which you don't even use, this will slow your pages down. If you want to select only the cells you need, you can use this.

### $data

This can be array or integer depending on $type.
You can use it this way;

```
array("username" => "admin");
```

Here you can use some extras with regex;
array("!username" => "LIKE!admin");

so when you are looping $data to put it in your query, if you see in the beginning of array key **!**, this might mean, don't use AND, use OR.

If you see in the beginning of array value LIKE! use it this way;

```
WHERE username LIKE 'admin'
```

### $order

This is also obvious.

### $pagination

`array(100 => 0)` Array key is **limit**, array value is **offset**.

Believe me you want to do something like this in order to make your life easy.

Of course I will suggest you to use PHP 5.3's feature static and make a databaseQuery class. This way you don't need to type $tableName in the first place and easier to work with OOP.

Simply your imagination is limit (:

I hope this helps.

Comment: That's good to know, but for what I'm doing this is a little too abstract. Have certainly learnt from it though. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After the examples above I needed something a little more specific to the queries I wanted to perform.

http://professionaldilettante.com/how-to-pass-parameters-as-query-string-to-your-php-functions/2010.11.22 runs though parsing arguments as a string, and as such I came up with this

```
private function parse_args($args) {

    // error check
    if( !is_string($args) )
        throw new Exception("\n\nfunction parse_args() expects a string, ". gettype($args). " passed\n\n");

    if( strpos($args,"&")  ):
    // if str contains &, assume multiple params
        $parts = explode("&",$args);
        for( $i=0, $len=count($parts); $i<$len; $i++ ):
            $tmp = explode("=",$parts[$i]);
            $parsed[$tmp[0]] = $tmp[1];
        endfor;
    else:
        $tmp = explode("=",$args);
        $parsed[$tmp[0]] = $tmp[1];
    endif;

    return $parsed;
}

 public static function sub_packages($args) {
    global $wpdb, $tbl_packages;

    $args = Packages::parse_args($args);

    // build query.
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_packages";

    if ( count($args) > 0 ) {
        $i = 0;
        foreach ( $args as $arg => $value) {
            if ( $i == 0 ) $sql .= " WHERE";
            elseif ( $i != $count ) $sql .= " AND";
            $sql .= " `$arg` = $value";
            $i++;
        }

    }

    return $wpdb->get_results( $sql, ARRAY_A);
 }
```